# Unable to call the declared prototype function on Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have the following prototype on the Array:

```
Array.prototype.testing = function(cb){
  var that = this
   function a(i) {
      console.log(i)
      setTimeout(function() {
          if (i+1  >= that.length) {
              return cb()
          } else {
              a(i + 1)
          }
      }, 1000)
   }
   a(0)
}
```

The prototype works well when called on an Array variable

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
arr.testing(function(){
  console.log("Ended")
}) // Prints 1 2 3 Ended to the console
```

But when called directly on an Array it throws a type error :

```
[1,2,3].testing(function(){
 console.log("Ended")
})  // Throws an typeError on [1,2,3], undefined
```

**Any help to understand why such is the case?**

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code. Where does it throw the typeError ???

Comment: If you didn't include a semicolon on the previous line, then the `[` will be interpreted as trying to access a property on the previous expression. Include a semi-colon before starting a line with `[`, `(` or anything that could be an infix or postfix operator. This is a pretty standard practice for those who take advantage of ASI.

Comment: Code is working fine. the code is error free